Disappearance of the style of the translated pages after updating the translation of the original page
I have a problem with using Elementor and WPML plugin in Wordpress. the problem: when I build a page with Elementor and translate with wpml, automatically translated pages will be created. after that I edit those translated page with elementor and set my custom style, for example specific font for translated page. the problem will occur here, if I edit original page and change or add some content then update this page and its translation again, the translated page style will be reset and will be as original page style. how can update translate without reseting translated pages style?

If you are using WPML you need to decouple the translated page from the original language if you are going to make changes to the translation. That's how WPML works. https://wpml.org/faq/how-to-disconnect-translations-from-the-default-language-page-or-post/
